# How edit and save the tridion default templates (TBB's)?

Tags: tridion

How to edit and save back the default tridion template building blocks say for Ex(Default Finish Actions) provided by SDL?

Where can i found the soucre of default TBB's? After locating and editing the TBB's, how to save back in TCM?

Comment: Please clarify your question. Do you want to edit default templates provided by SDL, or do you want to create and edit your own default templates?

Comment: I want to edit default templates provided by SDL.

Comment: Did you do research to find how you can develop and deploy template building blocks?

Comment: Two more reason not to change the default TBBs are 1) template creators can regenerate them, possibly over-writing any "edits" you've attempted and 2) being in your first publication makes these defaults hard to apply authorization or organize them in your, typically lower, design (template) publications.

Answer (score 3):

Editing default templates provided by SDL is not supported. They are stored in DLL and there's no way you can customize it. Maximum you can do is to disable some of the templates from being created. Alternatively you can can create your own set of default templates.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Template Builder to assemble and (test) run Compound Templates (Page and Component Templates). You can access the Template Builder from the Tools tab in the Ribbon.

The default TBBs should not be changed.

.NET TBBs are either C# fragments with the code directly accessible, or classes that implement the ITemplate interface.

Please see the following blog post to get you started:

http://www.createandbreak.net/2011/11/template-building-blocks-via-net.html

Answer (score 1):

The code for (an older version of) most of the Default Template Building Blocks can be found on the Tridion forum (http://forum.sdltridion.com).

(I don't have access anymore, but maybe somebody can edit my answer and provide the link)

As others have said though, you risk getting into support trouble if you simply modify and replace them. It might be better to:

1. take the code from the forum as a starting point
2. create your own variant, making the modifications you need
3. compile this into a new TBB
4. replace the standard TBB in the Default Finish Actions with your own variant

That way you can accomplish most things, without risking support problems. When they doubt whether you broke is, you can just swap out your own variant for the original and prove them wrong.

Comment: Submitted an edit with a [direct link to the post](https://forum.sdltridion.com/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=4653). The samples aren't the "real" default TBBs, but a version using public APIs.